# New type of backup system

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, backup, windows-server-2003

I'm currently using Windows based backup system. However, I would like something that makes accessing files easier so I can access files individuality and restore them and not have them all locked up into a compiled file. Is this possible?

Comment: Acronis lets you mount the archives it creates.  I use to simply duplicate my hdd once a week I suggest you do that.

Comment: Windows backup actually allows you to restore single files... So please specify further what you don't like about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commercial backup systems allow you to browse within your backups, regardless of the method in which they store the backups.  I've had success working with [BackupAssist](http://www.backupassist.com/index.html), despite them being bought and sold to different companies over the past 5 years.

Without knowing your specific requirements for a backup system, though, it's hard to make a confident recommendation.

Comment: Just need to backup Outlook Express emails, Desktop, Documents and simple stuff like that and able to access individual files with very little effort.

Comment: Then either BackupAssist or Acronis would work fine for you.